# Boot option to boot ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I was using ubuntu for over a month and whenever i would start my laptop ubuntu would boot automatically instead of windows 10 and i wanted to change that so i used a few commands but that ended up removing the boot option to boot ubuntu 20.04 lts from the boot menu. Before i was getting 2 boot options but now i get only one and thats for windows 10. A side note when i was go to the boot menu i would get the same name for both operating systems, Windows Boot Manager (name of ssd). I tried multiple ways using cmd prompt and terminal from try ubuntu in live usb but sadly there is still no boot option for ubuntu. Can anyone please help me

Comment: Please specify which commands you used.

Comment: Tip: Next time, use the BIOS setup to change the boot order.

Comment: You may need to totally reinstall grub and maybe kernel using Boot-Repair's advanced options. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Answer (score 0):

If you modified your `grub.cfg`, you can boot from a live usb, chroot into your installation and run update-grub to reset it